Private variables giving the warning not in use try removing the variable
I recently started learning Dart and come accross this warning in Dart pad. I don't why this warning is thrown. Can any body explain what is going on here.

I didn't expected the warning as the _name variable is in use in the constructer for setting tbe value.
Code:
void main() { 
  final ani = Animal('Tiger', 23);
 ani.setName = 'Tiggerr';
}

class Animal {
  String _name;
  final int age;

  Animal(this._name, this.age) {
    print('hello from constructer');
  }
  
  set setName(String newName){
    _name = newName;
  }
}



"use" in similar messages means "read by anyone". As it is a private variable, no one else than you can read it, and the compiler can tell that you don't read it.

The warning you're seeing indicates that the private variable _name is not used anywhere within the Animal class. In Dart, simply assigning a value to a variable (even in the constructor) does not count as "using" it. The compiler is expecting that the variable _name should either be printed, used in a calculation, passed to another method, or used to set another variable and actions like these.
For example, you can use _name in a method, print it, or use it in a conditional to satisfy the "used" condition:
class Animal {
  String _name;
  final int age;

  Animal(this._name, this.age) {
    print('hello from constructor');
  }

  set setName(String newName){
    _name = newName;
  }

  // Example usage of _name
  void printName() {
    print("The animal's name is $_name");
  }
}

In this updated version, I added a printName method to demonstrate how _name can be used. The warning should disappear once _name is utilized like this.
